# Trying to maintain a record of data in an excel cell

Tags: excel, data-structures

I am working with an excel sheet and wondering is there any way you can enter a currency value into a cell without completely removing the previous amount. I am trying to keep a record of numerous previous entries put into the excel sheet. It needs to be enabled so it is just a case of adding the new value and the previous values would be stored in the same cell. I know its a long shot but any help would be seriously appreciated. Would look something like below with the €1000 being the last entry and the €3000 being the first.

```
€1000

€1300

€1250

€3000
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot *squeeze* more than one value into a cell.

You could write VBA code that could, for example, use the Change event of the worksheet to add a comment to the cell and append the previous value to this comment. Or use this event to copy the previous value to a, perhaps hidden, worksheet.

For completeness I should mention that there is a Track Changes feature in Excel but it requires the workbook to be shared - which I do not recommend. Excel is not designed to work with multiple-users.

Comment: I have just been informed that the sheet has to be shared. Track changes feature only last as long as the worksheet is open and also only tracks one previous change as far as i can see and I need a full history of changes made to financial information. Thanks for your reply mate. I know i am probably not providing enough information.